# Making a package with Rcpp and trying to have a class reference another class

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I'm trying to write an R package that implements a board game. I want to use classes that refer to each other (e.g. a board has spaces and pieces on the spaces). However, when I try to build my package, I get the following error.

```
==> R CMD INSTALL --no-multiarch --with-keep.source testpkg

clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/Rcpp/include" -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c Family.cpp -o Family.o
* installing to library ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library’
* installing *source* package ‘testpkg’ ...
** using staged installation
** libs
clang++ -std=gnu++11 -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o testpkg.so Chicken.o Family.o RcppExports.o -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
ld: warning: text-based stub file /System/Library/Frameworks//CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation.tbd and library file /System/Library/Frameworks//CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation are out of sync. Falling back to library file for linking.
installing to /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/00LOCK-testpkg/00new/testpkg/libs
** R
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘testpkg’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/00LOCK-testpkg/00new/testpkg/libs/testpkg.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/00LOCK-testpkg/00new/testpkg/libs/testpkg.so, 6): Symbol not found: __ZN7ChickenC1Ei
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/00LOCK-testpkg/00new/testpkg/libs/testpkg.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/00LOCK-testpkg/00new/testpkg/libs/testpkg.so
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/testpkg’
* restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/testpkg’

Exited with status 1.
```

I've attached a reproducible example below. To give a more simple example this is trying to implement a Flock object that contains Chicken objects.

```
# testpkg-package.R
## usethis namespace: start
#' @useDynLib testpkg, .registration = TRUE
## usethis namespace: end
NULL

## usethis namespace: start
#' @import Rcpp
## usethis namespace: end
NULL
```

```
#zzz.R

#' @useDynLib testpkg
NULL

# Rcpp::loadModule("double_cpp", TRUE)
Rcpp::loadModule("chicken_cpp", TRUE)
Rcpp::loadModule("flock_cpp", TRUE)
```

```
// RcppExports.cpp

// Generated by using Rcpp::compileAttributes() -> do not edit by hand
// Generator token: 10BE3573-1514-4C36-9D1C-5A225CD40393

#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;


RcppExport SEXP _rcpp_module_boot_chicken_cpp();
RcppExport SEXP _rcpp_module_boot_flock_cpp();

static const R_CallMethodDef CallEntries[] = {
    {"_rcpp_module_boot_chicken_cpp", (DL_FUNC) &_rcpp_module_boot_chicken_cpp, 0},
    {"_rcpp_module_boot_flock_cpp", (DL_FUNC) &_rcpp_module_boot_flock_cpp, 0},
    {NULL, NULL, 0}
};

RcppExport void R_init_testpkg(DllInfo *dll) {
    R_registerRoutines(dll, NULL, CallEntries, NULL, NULL);
    R_useDynamicSymbols(dll, FALSE);
}
```

```
// Chicken.h

#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

class Chicken {
private:
  int id;
public:
  Chicken(int n);
};
```

```
// Chicken.cpp

#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

class Chicken {
private:
  int id;
public:
  Chicken(int n){
    id = n;
  }
};


RCPP_EXPOSED_CLASS(Chicken)
  RCPP_MODULE(chicken_cpp) {

    class_<Chicken>("Chicken")
    .constructor<int>()
    ;
  }
```

```
// Family.cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <vector>
#include "Chicken.h"

using namespace Rcpp;

class Flock {
private:
  std::string breed;
  std::vector<Chicken> chickens;
public:
  Flock(std::string b){
    breed = b;
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
      Chicken newChicken = Chicken(i);
      chickens.push_back(newChicken);
    }
  }


};


RCPP_EXPOSED_CLASS(Flock)
  RCPP_MODULE(flock_cpp) {

    class_<Flock>("Flock")
    .constructor<std::string>()
    ;
  }
```

These are the files I'm using. I'm not sure what this error entails and I've looked around a bit and couldn't find another example. I think that the flat namespace error says that the constructor for the Chicken class isn't found inside of the Flock class.

I've also just tried uninstalling and reinstalling R, RStudio, and Rcpp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are declaring a `Chicken` class in `Chicken.h`, which is known in `Family.cpp`. And you are declaring and defining a `Chicken` class in `Chicken.cpp`. These two classes are independent of each other. One possible solution is the include the declaration from `Chicken.h` also in `Chicken.cpp` and only define the methods instead of the full class:

```cpp
// Chicken.cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include "Chicken.h"

using namespace Rcpp;

Chicken::Chicken(int n){
    id = n;
}


RCPP_EXPOSED_CLASS(Chicken)
    RCPP_MODULE(chicken_cpp) {

        class_<Chicken>("Chicken")
        .constructor<int>()
        ;
    }
```

Alternatively you could move the full definition from `Chicken.cpp` to `Chicken.h`. Both approaches lead to a package that can be installed, I have not tested it further, though.

Comment: This is consistent with what I observed. I put all of the relevant pieces in one file since it was so small and had no problems.

Comment: Thank you! The Family.cpp file should've been called Flock.cpp. I also had gotten it to work by putting the two classes in the same file, but the real classes are going to be much larger which would've made that an inconvenient solution.